# Unable to locate offline partition despite metrics indicating its existence

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm working with a three-broker Apache Kafka cluster in a non-production environment.

Currently, our monitoring reports a metric, `kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_offlinepartitionscount`, indicating a single offline partition. This has been the case for at least a year based on our metrics retention.

Noteworthy events during this year:

- The cluster was upgraded from Kafka 3.2.3 to 3.3.2.
- Partitions were rebalanced.

Unfortunately, it seems these actions were performed without realizing the presence of offline partitions.

In an attempt to locate the offline partition, I've taken the following steps:

- Described all topics in the cluster searching for partitions with
  `Leader: -1` or `Leader: None`. No such partitions were found.
- Confirmed that all partitions have in-sync replicas (ISR).
- Tried toggling `unclean.leader.election.enable` from `false` to `true`, given it's a development cluster and potential data loss is acceptable. However, this did not resolve the issue.

Upon restarting the leader broker, leadership transitions to another broker, which then also reports the offline partition. This ensures that it's not a stale metrics issue.

I suspect there might be some lingering old metadata causing this, but I'm unsure how to confirm and resolve this. Any guidance on how to proceed with the investigation would be greatly appreciated.